# Приклад і прикладна математика

Tags: терміни, етимологія

Почну питання з коротенької історії:

> Питаю у сина-четвертокласника
>       - Ну як твій день у школі
>       - Сьогодні був урок прикладної математики
>       - Це як??
>       - Цілий урок розв'язували приклади!

Мені раніше здавалось що "приклад" і "прикладна" хоч і звучать як однокорінневі слова, насправді мають різне походження і семантику. Але тепер я засумнівався. Буду вдячний за пояснення

Comment: Це той тип питань, які на StackExchange називають opinion-based. Думаю, його варто переформулювати, щоб запрошувати до об'єктивних, науково-обґрунтованих відповідей, а не до дискусії.

Answer (score 9):

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976.:

> ПРИКЛАДНИ́Й, а, е. Який має практичне значення, не теоретичний.

З [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Прикладна математика — галузь математики, що розглядає застосування
>   математичних знань в інших сферах діяльності.

Наскільки я розумію, прикметник "прикладний" утворено від дієслова "прикладати" в значенні "застосовувати".

Comment: а у 'розв'язувати приклади' мається на увазі розв'язувати задачі за взірцем, який потім можна ніби буквально 'прикласти' до результату і порівняти форму

Comment: Так. Англійською цей розділ наиивається "applied mathematics". To aplly в т.ч. означає й прикладати.

Comment: @Chizh думаю, так. В теоретичному матеріалі було подано приклади задач з розв'язком, а після теорії - завдання, схожі на зразок.

Answer (score 5):

Як фаховий математик, пропоную утворити новий прикметник від слова „приклад“ на кшталт прикладовий. Авжеж у словниках цього слова немає. Але зате тепер будемо розрізняти прикладну і прикладову математику. Усі суперечності зникнуть. Як аргумент для такого новотвору наведу три прикметники з різним, але пов'язаним значення - дерев'яний, деревний, дерев'янистий. Відповідно, прикладова математика - це мала б бути математика на прикладах.

Comment: Щоб не подумали, що це пов'язане з [прикладом](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4_(%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F)). Але ідея хороша.